# Ann assignment in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have found a new assignment in python AST

```
AnnAssign(expr target, expr annotation, expr? value, int simple)
```

Can anyone give me an example of AssAssign with python3.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

`AnnAssign` is an *annotated assignment* which refers to variable annotations introduced with [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/). This allows type annotations (used for [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)) to be attached to normal variables.

The annotated assignment is a combination of a variable annotation with the assignment of a value. An example would look like this:

```
foo : int = 42
```

Here, `foo` is the variable name and `int` is the type annotation.

We can use the `ast` module to verify that this does indeed create an `AnnAssign` node and see how these nodes look like:

```
>>> t = ast.parse('foo : int = 42')
>>> t.body[0]
<_ast.AnnAssign object at 0x0000025A80DF0860>
```

Like a normal assignment, the target is in the `target` property. Note that an annotated assignment only has a *single target*, so tuple assignments explicitly do not work. The node also has a `value` property for the value:

```
>>> t.body[0].target
<_ast.Name object at 0x0000025A80DF0828>
>>> t.body[0].target.id
'foo'
>>> t.body[0].value
<_ast.Num object at 0x0000025A80DF0CF8>
>>> t.body[0].value.n
42
```

The annotation is accessible with the `annotation` property. Annotations are Python objects, so in this case we see another `Name` node:

```
>>> t.body[0].annotation
<_ast.Name object at 0x0000025A80DF0898>
>>> t.body[0].annotation.id
'int'
```